# Does the comment length limit depend on reputation?

Tags: support

I could not find clarification in help pages.

If yes, what are the milestones or such?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's 600 characters for every one of us.

Comment: I thought it was 400 then 500 then noticed to be 600. Seems I was just inattentive.

Comment: You should have told him it was 800 for all of us, ha ha.